# How to show JSON response from APEX inside toast as error message

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

I have a form to create A student, inside that form I have field which go through validation via API, now I get a correct logs in APEX and also when print it with `console.log();` but I have a trouble to show error message in toast to user.

This is function:

```
    sync handleFormSubmit(event)  { 
    event.preventDefault();
    const fields = event.detail.fields;
    const validationResult = await validateUMCN({ emso: fields.UMCN__c});
    if(validationResult.success) {
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
    const event = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Student',
        message: 'Student created successfully',
        variant: 'success'
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);    
   } else {
    const event = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Student',
        message: 'Student is not created',
        variant: 'error'
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);        
    console.log(validationResult);
        }
  }
```

So when I `console.log(validationResult);` I get a good response in console, but I have trouble to show it in toast.

I tried with `message: 'Student is not created' + JSON.stringify(this.validationResult),` but that doesn't work, ike that I get `Student is not createdundefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`validationResult` is a local variable, so you do not use `this.` to access it. You can render the message with something like:

```
message: `Student was not created. Reason: ${validationResult.message}`,
```

Note that this is using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which uses `` ` `` instead of `'` or `"`.

Comment: Thanks. That is good

Comment: Btw. one more question if its not problem, I have a list where I display stuff from object A inside Object A I save object B that is lookup, and when I list that Object B I get ID instead of name. For examle Object A have Object B (lookup) now When I want to display that Object B in Object A list like this `item.Object__b` I got Id instead of name, how I can set this so actually to return field fro ObjectB

Comment: I mean I have `item.Title__c` > that is `Object A`, but in `Object A` I have `lookup of Object B` Now I want to get field from `Object B` and list it, like `item.ObjectB__c.firstName__c`

Comment: @FrostyNah In Apex, use the relationship notation `__r`, as in `item.ObjectB__r.FirstName__c`. For lightning-record-edit-form, the lightning-input-field should render the correct values for you, however. Typically, you only need to worry about the ID value.

Comment: Thanks again, I made it